# Caching compiled javascripts in node.js

Tags: c++, node.js, v8

I have an application running using Node.js where it would seem the compilation of the individual javascript files takes too long. I would like to try and cache the compiled data so that subsequent compilations of the same scripts will be sped up.

The approach I have been attempting so far is to put code into node.js ContextifyScript::New that would use kProduceCodeCache in order to produce a ScriptCompiler::CachedData for the scripts that are compiled here. I would then save the CachedData to disk, and on subsequent compilations (also after restarting node.js executable) I was planning on reading the CachedData from disk and passing it along to CompileUnbound.

From the description of CachedData in the v8 header I assumed this was the intended purpose with the class. However during serialization of the compiled code, I get a debug-assertion failure in CodeSerializer::SerializeObject in this code:

```
// The code-caches link to context-specific code objects, which
// the startup and context serializes cannot currently handle.
DCHECK(!heap_object->IsMap() ||
 Map::cast(heap_object)->code_cache() ==
     heap_object->GetHeap()->empty_fixed_array());
```

I do not understand exactly what the problem is here. I know the javascript in question can be compiled and serialized, because if I do this without using Node.js (just following the examples provided in the v8 tests), I am able to compile and serialize. 
So, does anyone know what this means, and what I'm doing wrong? Is it possible to achieve the caching of compiled data in some other way?